# System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 12. Как нормально вывести значение 12 без текста в excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Привет всем.
Как вывести значение 12 из textbox1 в файл excel в ячейке А1. Т.е. ввожу значение в textbox1 и вывожу на excel это значение.
У меня выводит вместо 12, вот это в ячейке А1 со значением "**System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 12**".

Переменная **int a1** и textbox объявлены в **partial class Main**

вот так беру значение

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
        //Книга.
        ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        //Таблица.
        ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];

        //Значения [y - строка,x - столбец]
        ObjWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = this.a1;
        //Вызываем нашу созданную эксельку.
        ObjExcel.Visible = true;
        ObjExcel.UserControl = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, заменив строку

```
ObjWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = this.a1;
```

на строку

```
ObjWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = this.a1.text;
```

Comment: вообще то на секунду ранее сам разобрался, но спасибо!!! Принимаю ответ